# how to apply where clause for included table's jsonb column using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, where-clause

I have 2 tables in postgres database.

```
Table_A
--------
id BIGINT
metadata JSONB

Table_B
--------
id BIGINT
a_id BIGINT
metadata JSONB
```

**Data**

```
Table_A
id | metadata
1  | {'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'xyz'}

Table_B
id | a_id | metadata
1  | 1    | {'country': 'IN', 'address': 'Banglore'}
2  | 1    | {'country': 'US', 'address': 'New York'}
3  | 1    | {'country': 'IN', 'address': 'Hydrabad'}
```

I am using sequelize and trying to apply where cluse for included table's jsonb column.

**Example:**

```
let query = {
        where: {
            '$table_b.metadata.address$': 'Banglore'
        }
        include: [
            {
                model: Table_B,
                as: 'table_b'
            }
        ]
    };
    
Table_A.findAndCountAll(query).then((result)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

But I am getting below error

```
original: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "table_b->metadata"
  at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
  at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
  at Parser.parse (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
  at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
  at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
  at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
```

Can anyone help how to apply where clause for included table's jsonb column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way.

```
const query = {
    include: [{
        model: Table_B,
        as: 'table_b',
        where: {
            metadata: {
                address: 'Banglore'
            }
        }
    }]
};
```

This should work with matching a subset of properties within a JSONB field.

==============================================

Update:

If you would like to apply `where` at the top level, you wrap with `JSON.stringify` and use `Op.contains` to do a partial match on a subset of properties.

```
const query = {
    where: {
        '$table_b.metadata$': {
             [Op.contains]: JSON.stringify({
                 address: 'Banglore'
             }
        })
    },
    include: [{
        model: Table_B,
        as: 'table_b'
    }]
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way to apply the where clause in root. Because we are dynamically generating the where clause in our original code. It's working for non jsonb column but not working for jsonb

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer, please check it out.

Comment: It'll work if JSONB column has only property called address. but it'll not work if it has multiple property with address

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "multiple property with address"? (address is array?) Could you update your question to show that in example so that I can have the correct sample data?

Comment: Question is updated with table data, please check

Comment: @SangramBadi Do you want to query "country" & "address" together? is it AND or OR condition? or Do you mean you want to query "Banglore", "New York" as OR condition for address?

Comment: I wanted to query single value. Example : where metadata.address like 'Banglore'

Comment: Updated. (Use `Op.contains`)

Comment: could you please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606655/how-to-convert-postgresql-query-to-sequalize-js-query