# How to convert PostgreSQL query to Sequalize.js query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table called **Test**, which has below data

**Table**

```
Test
-----
id | org_id | metadata (It's a JSONB column)
---------------------------------------
1  | 65t7   | { "term": "price_12", "status": "Declined", "switch": "Cisco", "capacity": 109951162777600 }
2  | 65t7   | { "term": "price_13", "status": "Declined", "switch": "Cisco", "capacity": 988951162656789 }
3  | 45t4   | { "term": "amice_12", "status": "Declined", "switch": "Cisco", "capacity": 109951162777600 }
4  | 65t7   | { "term": "werwe_12", "status": "Declined", "switch": "Cisco", "capacity": 174637726481230 }
```

I am running below query and getting the output

```
SELECT * FROM public.Test 
where org_id = '65t7' 
and metadata->> 'term' iLike '%ice_12%' 
and (metadata->> 'capacity')::bigint = 109951162777600;
```

**Output**

```
id | org_id | metadata
---------------------------------------
1  | 65t7   | { "term": "price_12", "status": "Declined", "switch": "Cisco", "capacity": 109951162777600 }
```

I am trying to convert it to Sequalize format query

**Code**

```
let final = {
    where: {
        org_id : '65t7',
        [Op.and]: [
            { 'metadata.term':  { [Op.iLike]: '%ice_12%' }},
            { 'metadata.capacity':  { [Op.is]: 109951162777600 }}
        ]
    }
    limit: 500,
    offset: 0
};

const res = Test.findAndCountAll(final);
```

**Error:**

```
at Query.run (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:50:25)
    at C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sequelize.js:300:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.rawSelect (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:415:18)
    at async Function.aggregate (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\model.js:1229:19)
    at async Function.count (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\model.js:1252:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Function.findAndCountAll (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\model.js:1268:27) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: column test.metadata.term does not exist
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Project\test\FilterTest\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
      at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
      at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For searching JSONB, you can not use "." to access key within the JSON field.

Instead, try writing a plain object.

I removed `[Op.and]` since that is the default connector when you have multiple key-value in `where` options. I also removed `[Op.is]` which is not necessary.

```
const final = {
    where: {
        org_id : '65t7',
        metadata: { 
            term: {
                [Op.iLike]: '%ice_12%' 
            },
            capacity: 109951162777600
        }
    }
    limit: 500,
    offset: 0
};

const res = await Test.findAndCountAll(final);
```

Note that using offset/limit without order, your result won't be guaranteed to be same every time. If you are planning to do pagination, add `order` option to make sure the offset/limit is segmenting the same subset all the time.